# Rails Nested Model Form updating using existing data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my app:

```
A song has many setlists through allocations
A setlist has many songs through allocations
allocations belong to setlists and songs
```

I'm trying to add a song from the existing library to a set list using the following form:

```
 <% @songs.each do |song| %>
            <tr>
               <%= nested_form_for(@setlist.allocations.build(song_id: song.id)) do |f| %>
               <td><%= song.title %></td>
               <td><%= song.artist %></td>
               <td><%= song.key %></td>
               <td>
                     <div><%= f.hidden_field :song_id %></div>
                  <%= f.submit "ADD", class: "btn btn-small btn-primary" %>
                  <% end %>

               </td>
            </tr>
          <% end %>
```

In my setlists controller I have:

```
def edit
    @songs = Song.all(order: 'title')
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    @setSongs = @setlist.songs
    @allocations = Allocation.where("setlist_id =?", @setlist) 
  end

  def update
    @setlist = Setlist.find(params[:id])
    song = Song.find(params[:song_id])
    @setlist.allocate!(song)
    if @setlist.update_attributes(params[:setlist])
      # Handle a successful update.
      flash[:success] = "SAVED!"
      redirect_to setlists_path
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

The allocate method is specified in the setlist model as:

```
 def allocate!(song)
    allocations.create!(song_id: song.id)
  end
```

At the moment it returns the following whenever I click to add songs to the setlist.

NoMethodError in SetlistsController#update
undefined method `id' for :song:Symbol

The bug is also wierd in that it only does the error above for the first record in the table, whilst all the others render the "error" page for when a record hasn't been added.

Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the Symbol `:song` to `allocate!` in

```
@setlist.allocate!(:song)
```

when `allocate!` is expecting an instance of `Song` to be passed. The `:song` symbol has no method `.id`, hence the error.

If you're trying to pass the `Song` related to

```
<%= f.hidden_field :song_id %>
```

you must first get the `Song`.

```
song = Song.find(params[:allocation][:song_id])
@setlist.allocate!(song)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt answer. I've edited the controller like you've said (see the edit above) but the error still seems to be persisting. The weirdest part is that only the first song in the table renders the actual error page whereas upon trying to add any of the other songs, it redirects to a page specified by the allocations controller's create action and flashes an error message.

Comment: You did not edit your code in the Question to reflect my answer. You're still incorrectly passing the `:song` symbol to `allocate`.

Comment: My apologies, I've edited it properly now, but it's still throwing back errors, albeit different ones now. The first entry still states `Couldn't find Song without an ID`whilst the others are now complaining they can't find a setlist without an id

Comment: I updated my answer to guide you towards correcting your incorrect `params` keys.

Comment: The string returned for the first entry in the table states that the song id is being passed?

`{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"heY50sDamWexuWXDWbe+vyhNQX1Igi3+X1TrFH9uFho=",
 "setlist"=>{"date(1i)"=>"2017",
 "date(2i)"=>"12",
 "date(3i)"=>"20",
 "morning"=>"false"},
 "allocation"=>{"song_id"=>"14"},
 "commit"=>"ADD",
 "id"=>"13"}`

Comment: Please can you update your post or comment here as to what else you missed?